# Use optimistic locking to to snapshot pricing information for a marketplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, architecture

I am designing a two-sided market place, of which owners can rent out their assets for a price to renters.

Let's take an example of `asset.rb`

```
daily_rate :decimal
hourly_rate :decimal
```

Hypothetically if a renter wants to rent an asset. he/she will submit a request. It is reasonable that the renter should be paying the price of what he/she sees when making the request. I want to be able to lock in the price information so even when the owner changes the price during the booking. We can fetch the snapshot of that pricing when the request is made.

I have several ideas:

**1) Store all price fields in the request model**

It is the easiest method to store a snapshot of all the prices in the request model. It is what we are using now.

**2) [Haven't tried] Use gems like papertrail**

There are libraries and gems where I can use to store the historic changes of the `price` model. I read about optimistic locking the model for versioning. But I don't know if it is common practice to use this for storing pricing information as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this by having a separate model for asset and the `Order` that is created when a renter actually wants to rent something. Basically, your order would have at least the same two attributes as your asset (i.e., `daily_rate` and `hourly_rate`) as well as third attribute which you might call `status`.

When a potential renter selects an asset they want, your app will create an `order` instance with the current daily_rate and hourly_rate from the asset and the status `"unconfirmed"` (either as a String or enum). You should then show the renter a confirmation page with those rates and ask them if they still want to go ahead with the rental. If they say yes, you can set `status` to `"confirmed"`.

This structure will prevent the users that rent assets from ever being able to change prices after the renter has placed an order. Even if the user renting the asset changed the prices in between the renter's initial request and the confirmation, the renter will have the option of completing the order at the prices available when they placed their initial request.

Comment: So you are suggesting option 1

Comment: Well I definitely wouldn't store the rate on the request object itself since that opens it up to tampering. I would create an actual model with attributes stored in the DB. Besides, you'll probably want it later for generating receipts, record keeping, etc.